# How to reverse MACStringToOUI() in ClickHouse so I get the mac address with empty last 3 octets

Tags: clickhouse

```sql
SELECT MACStringToOUI('aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff')
```

gives me `11189196` which are the first three octets as a UInt64 number.

I'd like to convert it back to MacAddress so the desired result is `aa:bb:cc:00:00:00`.

I believe there's no native function for that. Do I have to move bits manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*256^3

```
SELECT MACNumToString(MACStringToOUI('aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff')*256*256*256) r;
Query id: 3a3637c3-d068-4b00-9024-01129517c3e2

┌─r─────────────────┐
│ AA:BB:CC:00:00:00 │
└───────────────────┘
```